# Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain in nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to install [nuclide](https://nuclide.io/) package in `atom` for the development of `react-native`. I am not sure what is the reason for below error. Can anyone suggest me how to resolve this.

Thanks in advance

```
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/asap/-/asap-2.0.5.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-regex/-/ansi-regex-2.1.1.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/cheerio/-/cheerio-0.22.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/chalk/-/chalk-1.1.3.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/boom/-/boom-2.10.1.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/async-to-generator/-/async-to-generator-1.0.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/assert-plus/-/assert-plus-0.2.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/boolbase/-/boolbase-1.0.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/delayed-stream/-/delayed-stream-1.0.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/array-reduce/-/array-reduce-0.0.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/dashdash/-/dashdash-1.14.1.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/connect/-/connect-3.5.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-styles/-/ansi-styles-2.2.1.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

Comment: Perhaps someone/something (e.g. proxy -- either explicit or otherwise) is MITM'ing your traffic? The certificate currently used by registry.npmjs.org should have been issued by GlobalSign Extended Validation. Try visiting https://registry.npmjs.org in your browser and check the certificate issuer from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can directly clone the nuclide package and install .here all the procedure is shown.
Run the following commands in terminal

```
# Clone the source
$ git clone https://github.com/facebook/nuclide.git
$ cd nuclide
# Install dependencies
$ npm install
# Link the 'nuclide' package to Atom's package directory
$ apm link
```

Verify the installation by:

```
Open Atom.
Go to Atom | Preferences.
Click on Packages.
Verify nuclide as one of the packages
```

or refer to this url 
http://nuclide.io/docs/advanced-topics/building-from-source/#linux__building